# How to get a existing controller object from storyboard file?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard, viewcontroller, popover

I'm new for storyboard file in iOS.

As I know, the objects (view controller object included) that I drag into the storyboard are existing instances, not a virtual class.

However, who owns those instances in application? AppDelegate? or others?

Now I'm trying to get a controller object from storyboard file and make the view of that controller shown with popover. (I don't want to drag the relation lines among the objects completely, and use `-addSubView:` to implement all the sub-objects in popover view.) I think there must be a way to access the independent controller in stroyboard file.

Any suggestions?

If I implement the view controller in `MyViewController` class and init a new object with `[MyViewController new]`, this would be another object that's not I want, I think.

Comment: if you want to get introduced to storyboards on iOS check this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1), you will also find the answer to your question in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within your view controller you can access the storyboard and instantiate the new view controller:

```
NewViewController *newVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyNewViewController"];
```

You may then use this in your popover.